# How to get ride of Parsing Error: Unexpected Token while working with React? I've used ESLint and Prettier

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to make a form in React using MUI, and I've the following code :-

```
const textFields = [
  {
    label: 'Name',
    placeholder: 'Enter a company name',
  },
  {
    label: 'Address',
    placeholder: 'Enter a company address',
  },
  {
    label: 'Email',
    placeholder: 'Enter an email',
  },
  {
    label: 'Telephone Number',
    placeholder: 'Enter a telephone number',
  },
]

return (<Box
            width={400}
            height={400}
            p={3}
            borderRadius={3}
            bgcolor='background.default'
            color='text.primary'
          >
            <Typography textAlign='center' color='black' variant='h6'>
              Add Company
            </Typography>
            <Box marginTop={3}>
              textFields.map((textField) => (

              <TextField
                sx={{
                  mt: 2,
                  mb: 2,
                }}
                fullWidth
                label={textField.label}
                placeholder={textField.placeholder}
              />
              ))
              
            </Box>
)
```

**but there's a problem when I try to map the textFields array, Parsing Error: Unexpected token arises in => part**

Answer (score 1):

In your above code snippet, the curly braces are missing to run the map functions. Try this below one:

`{textFields.map(() => ()}`

Comment: And also don't forget to use `key` attribute when using `map`.